# Is Jenkins running package tests as root?

Tags: catkin, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently converted a package to catkin. The unit tests work on my machine, but one of them fails on Jenkins.

The test tries to write calibration information to a non-writable file and directory, which should fail. On my machine running as me, it does. On Jenkins the write succeeds (which it should not).

The simplest explanation is if Jenkins is running the unit tests as root.

Is that being done?

It seems wrong. Can it be changed?

Those tests worked fine on Hudson before the catkin migration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59431/is-jenkins-running-package-tests-as-root?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened a [defect ticket](//github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/issues/27).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0